# Photos how to get rid off the home screen

Tags: photos

Hi can anybody help just got the android tablet,we have been looking

For a car,so to save photos it tells me add to home screen ,which was  good but now we have a car ,how do I get rid of the photos from my home screen ,would be glad of any help .thanks Alan

Answer (score 0):

To remove a shortcut from your home screen, just hold down your finger on it until a little **remove** label appears. (It probably has an X icon or a picture of a rubbish bin, but that depends on what tablet you have.) Without lifting your finger, drag the icon over to the **remove** label and then let go to drop it there.